# Getting error when trying to use IPyConsole Plugin in QGIS 2.18.16

Tags: pyqgis, error, qgis-2, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to use the IPyConsole Plugin and the error I receive tells me I have to install IPython 3.1.0 or Jupyter 1.0.0. So I followed the link they gave me and installed Anaconda 2.17 and then 3 but still receive the same error. I am using Windows 7 Enterprise.

The exception error that is popping up is:

> NO module name IPYthon.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget.

Comment: You must install these modules in the Python version used by QGIS and not in another version of Python. (Anaconda for example)

Comment: I am having the same problem right now, and can't figure out how to do what you are suggesting @gene ... How would one install these modules in the correct place?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed QGIS using the OSGeo4W setup option, you can use the OSGeo4W Shell to access the QGIS version of python and perform `pip install` commands (*python* for QGIS 2.x or *python3* for QGIS 3.x).

On Windows the standard command should be:
`python -m pip install jupyter==1.0.0 qtconsole`